# 'bool' object has no attribute 'has_header' when uploading via a FileField in my admin

Tags: django, uploading, filefield

My models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Song(models.Model):
   uploader = models.ForeignKey(User)
   date_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

   song_file = models.FileField(upload_to='music/', max_length=100)
   artist = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
   genre = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

   def __unicode__(self):
      return u'%s' % (self.song_file)
```

My admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from uploader.models import Song
from django.db import models


class SongAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

   list_display = ('song_file', 'title', 'artist', 'genre', 'uploader')

   search_fields = ('song_file', 'uploader', 'genre', 'title')
   fields = ('song_file', 'title', 'artist', 'genre')

admin.site.register(Song, SongAdmin)
```

The file gets uploaded (I see it in my media folder) but it doesnt display in my admin page and when the file does get uploaded I get:

```
'bool' object has no attribute 'has_header' when uploading via a FileField in my admin
```

Am I missing something obvious here? Pretty new to django.

Comment: Why can't people quote the actual traceback? It has real, useful information, it's not just a load of random junk.

Comment: The traceback didn't provide anything useful. But I will next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with Pinax. Updated to the latest git and everything works now!

Answer (score 0):

Found this somewhere else on the net, the problem is in the HideSensitiveFieldsMiddleware and the way to work around it (for debug) is to just comment out that middleware like so

```
    "pinax.middleware.security.HideSensistiveFieldsMiddleware",
+#    "pinax.middleware.security.HideSensistiveFieldsMiddleware",
```

in your settings file, probably should leave that middleware in for non debug environments